# Create Zip file of Github Reporitory using a workflow which runs on [windows-latest]

Tags: github, github-actions, github-for-windows

I'm trying to create a zip file of my repository using git hub workflow. Below is the code:

```
name: .NET    
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: [windows-latest]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: Set Up MS Build
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1
      
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: nuget restore Solution.sln
      
    - name: Build Solution
      run: msbuild Solution.sln 
    
    - name: Creating Zip
      run: zip -r release.zip . -x ".git/*" ".github/*"
```

This gives me an error :

```
> The term 'zip' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function,
> script file, or executable program
```

.
Figured out that, zip command is not available on Windows.
Tried googling, but no luck. Any resources would be helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try powershell `Compress-Archive`

for example

```
- run: Compress-Archive -Path folder/* -Destination new.zip
```

Comment: how does this work? should I use the `shell: powershell` attribute? or will this work out of the box?

Comment: @0xdeadbeef `shell: powershell` is default on a windows runner for `run`. works out of box

Answer (score -3):

To use `zip` just change `windows-latest` onto `linux-latest`.

Comment: The question explicitly asks, "…which runs on `[windows-latest]`". Telling them to switch to `[linux-latest]` doesn't answer the question. Presumably, they have a good reason for preferring that their actions run in Windows, such as potential dependencies on Windows-only commands or packages.